# Google Maps kml file limit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a limit to the number of kml files which can be rendered? I know there is a file size limit but I seem to be hitting another limit.

The error thrown is

```
GET https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=kml%3AcXOw0bjKUSgN5kcEMpDT…7Capi%3A3%7Cclient%3A2&x=67&y=98&z=8&w=256&h=256&source=apiv3&token=127990 414 (Request-URI Too Large) mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=kml%3AcXOw0bjKUSgN5kcEMpDTUkENzfIp…api%3A3%7Cclient%3A2&x=67&y=98&z=8&w=256&h=256&source=apiv3&token=127990:1
```

Below is an example of what I am attempting to accomplish.

http://tinyurl.com/qg5enx8

Comment: Seems to work after the map is initialized. `American Samoa`'s URL doesn't seem to work, unless the space is removed.

Comment: I fixed that entry. But it still doesnt work, I receive errors on all the kml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport)

> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. 
>   If you exceed this limit, none of your layers will display. The limit is based on the total 
>   length of all URLs passed to the KMLLayer class, and consequently will vary by application; 
>   on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20 layers without hitting the limit.

Comment: I guess I will need to parse them out and render on the client if layers > 10

Answer (score 1):

Try using Network links: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut?csw=1#network_links

I know it sounds a but more cumbersome, but it helps when loading lots of KML Data at once.

Another option is to change your approach and use [Google Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started) through the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js). Basically to start on this route, you'll need to load the script: https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init where onload refers to YOUR javascript function to run once the script is loaded. Mine looks something like this:

```
function init() {
    gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey( YOUR_API_KEY_AS_STRING );
        gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({sql:["SELECT * FROM", TABLE_NAME].join(' '), fields:'rows, columns'}).execute( function(json) {
            //Do what you need to parse the json response
            //Set up KML Layers
            //etc... make sure to check if maps is loaded too
            json.rows.forEach( function(t) {
                console.log( t );
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you saying I would have one kml/kmz which would use network links to reference other kmls? I dont know if that will work for what I am attempting to accomplish. I need to be able to add a large number or polygons and remove them dynamically.

Comment: @user3032973, with this method, you can merge many of your polygons into a single KML and reference that. Try it out!

Comment: Hi, yeah I am aware you can render multiple polygons in a single KML. however one piece of functionality I am looking for is the ability to add/remove polygons on the client side. This will either require me to have a KML for each polygon. Or to parse a single kml file and render these polygons on the client side.

Comment: I have something similar I'm working on. And to accomplish this, I have set up my data inside a Fusion Table. The Location Field specifies the KML Data for it, and I've created an interface to add/remove polygons/markers which in turn update the Fusion Table. Maybe it's about approach?

Comment: Thanks for the information! I had a large google maps project recently but I was able to get away with dynamically build kml files(3). I know you can query the fusion tables but thats about it. Ill need to do some research into this.

Comment: Updated my answer @user3032973. This should get you going on that path.